# Access to description attribute of an Property template construct parameter

Tags: m2doc

I want to use a parameterized template construct to access the attributes of a Property object to generate some output in a word document. When I use the template with some basic types (e.g. Integer or String) it works fine but when I've tried to use a Property object, I can only access the "name" attribute but not e.g. the description attribute. Using the unit test recursiveEObject-template as a starting point, my template looks like this:

```
{ m:template mytest(element : ecore::ENamedElement) }
{ m: element.description }
{ m:endtemplate }
```

And I get the following error message:

```
{ m:element.        <---Feature description not found in EClass ENamedElement description }
```

I assume that the type of my parameter is just wrong and I need to change it or cast it to some derived Property child class of ENamedElement but I did not find the correct class. Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to change the type of the parameter element to the type of the object that is holding the description feature. You will also need to import the EPackage containing the EClass.

For instance if I want to use the description of a Capella object:

```
{ m:template mytest(element : capellacore::CapellaElement) }
{ m: element.description }
{ m:endtemplate }
```

then import the following nsURI (may change according to the version of Capella):

http://www.polarsys.org/capella/core/core/1.4.0

using the [template property wizard](http://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#template-properties-wizard)